# How to fix missing function in wp-cron?

Tags: wp-cron, scheduled-posts

One of my sites consistently fails to publish scheduled posts. I've tried disabling plugins, using Twenty Twelve, etc. with no luck.

I installed the Core Control plugin and noticed that there is no function associated with the publish_future_post hook. On my other sites, there is a hooked function check_and_publish_future_post() but it's missing on this particular site.

My questions are (1) how the heck did this happen and (2) how do I fix it? I've tried a clean install of Wordpress (other than wp-content) with no change. I've reached the limit of what I'm comfortable doing without some guidance, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Comment: Okay, I still have no idea what went wrong but I did manage to fix it. I added a function to force the correct time zone, even though it's set correctly on the server and in Settings > General. I have no idea why this particular install doesn't want to work like the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also disable the auto wp-cron from loading and setup a manual cron job on your server.

Add the following line to your Wp-config.php
`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

and then on your server/control panel create a cron job to run the following:

`wget http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

I run mine every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! That might be an option as well, though I hate the thought of scheduling everything manually.